# Append ul in li using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About
        <ul>
            <li>About1</li>
            <li>About1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My code

```
function createMenuBar(mainMenuList) {

  for(var l = 0; l < mainMenuList.length; l++) {
    var item = mainMenuList[l];

    if(item) {
        var mainItem = $("<li></li>"); 
        var mainItemLink = $("<a></a>", {
            href : item.Url,
            text : item.Title
        });

        mainItem.append(mainItemLink);          
        if(item.SubMenus.length) {
            var subMenu = getSubMenu(item.SubMenus);

            mainItem.append(subMenu);
        }

        $('#masterMenu ul').append(mainItem);
    }
  }
}


function getSubMenu(submenuList){
   var subMenuUl = $("<ul></ul>");

    for(var i = 0 ; i < submenuList.length; i++) {
        var subMenuItem = $("<li></li>");  
        var subMenuItemLink = $("<a></a>", {
          href : submenuList[i].Url,
          text : submenuList[i].Title
        });

        subMenuItem.append(subMenuItemLink);
        subMenuUl.append(subMenuItem);
    }

    return subMenuUl;
}
```

Comment: Achieve what? What have you tried?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly??

Comment: See the `append` function.

Comment: `return $("<p></p>").append(subMenuUl);` what do you want to make here?

Comment: see it now. Not working also

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can try using the `append` method.

```
$('ul.my-ul li.in-this-li').append('<ul><li></li><li></li></ul>');
```

Comment: I'm not sure how making up arbitrary class names for vague elements, and adding empty elements to them answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is greate documentation http://api.jquery.com/append/ about how works append.

My Example :

```js
$(function() {
  var ulToApppend = $('.append-ul');
  $('.append-li').append(ulToApppend);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='main-ul'>
  <li class='append-li'>1 li</li>
  <li>2 li</li>
  <li>3 li</li>
</ul>


<ul class='append-ul'>
  <li>10 li</li>
  <li>20 li</li>
  <li>30 li</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: give an example how I can add ul to li